# How to convert LaserScan to PCLPointCloud2?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pcl, sensor-msgs, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, I'm trying to read the laserscanner data  and convert to PCLPointCloud2 for processing. I took the [pcl_ros tutorial code](https://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials/hydro?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=example_voxelgrid.cpp) and adapted the callback parameter to `sensor_msgs::LaserScan`. However, I get a compiler error:

```
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:118:11: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >&’ from expression of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >’
```

This is the code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
// PCL specific includes
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include "laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h"
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

ros::Publisher pub;

void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan &scan_msg)
{
    // Container for original & filtered data
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 *cloud = new pcl::PCLPointCloud2;
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr cloudPtr(cloud);
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud_filtered;

    // Convert to PCL data type
    laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pntCloud;
    projector_.projectLaser(scan_msg, pntCloud, 30.0);

    pcl_conversions::toPCL(pntCloud, *cloud);

    // Perform the actual filtering
    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud(cloudPtr);
    sor.setLeafSize(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    sor.filter(cloud_filtered);

    // Convert to ROS data type
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
    pcl_conversions::moveFromPCL(cloud_filtered, output);

    // Publish the data
    pub.publish(output);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Initialize ROS
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("input", 1000, &cloud_cb);

    // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
    pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("output", 1);

    // Spin
    ros::spin();
}
```

I can change the callback paramater to `const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr&`. However, I have issue with the `projector_.projectLaser(scan_msg, pntCloud, 30.0);` since this fucntion needs `LaserScan&`. How can I fix this code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363554/how-to-convert-laserscan-to-pclpointcloud2?/) by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2020-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not tried to run and validate the code, but you should as you say at the end, "change the callback parameter to `const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr&` ".  If you do not do that the callback will never work because ROS needs it to be a boost shared_ptr.

So with that back to the way that it should be, we need to fix passing the `projector_.projectLaser(scan_msg, pntCloud, 30.0);` the right argument. To do this you will need to [dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) the smart_ptr.

So the call would look like:

```
projector_.projectLaser(*scan_msg, pntCloud, 30.0);
```

I think this should solve your concern about "since this function needs `LaserScan&`. How can I fix this code?"

**EDIT** You may actually need to double dereference it, because the callback is passed is a reference to a smart_ptr, so it would actually look like:

```
 projector_.projectLaser(**scan_msg, pntCloud, 30.0);
```

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-16**:
Thanks! So `sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr` is another type of pointer. `projector_.projectLaser(*scan_msg, pntCloud, 30.0);` once deference works. What is the reason not to use `void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan* scanmsg)`? `ConstPtr` is not a general C++ type.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-17**:
See [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/212857/what-is-constptr/) to understand the ConstPtr

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the right subscribe signatuure for laser scannner is

```
void laserCB(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg){
ROS_INFO("LaserScan (val,angle)=(%f,%f", msg->range_min,msg->angle_min);
}
```

and for the projector you write

```
 projector_.projectLaser(*msg, pntCloud, 30.0);
```

you find an working example plus description here

[ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry)

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-16**:
thanks for the answer!

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-16**:
After build the program, how can I visualize it in rviz? Adding the PointCloud2 in Rviz, I got this error:

```
For frame [laser]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
```

Somehow I need to assign a map frame or something similar.